# How to read a mifare 1k card through ACR122U NFC Tag reader connected to local machine in a web application

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, applet, mifare

Read a mifare 1k card through my web application which is connected to local system which is browsing my web application. 
The reader I am using is ACR122U NFC Tag reader.
I got sample code for window application to access the reader and read the UID of NFC tag.
but I want to read the value in my Web site.
Work flow is:

1. My web site page is opened  in a browser of a machine. That page has a button "Read UID".
2. After clicking of this button I want to read the NFC Tag UID through  ACR122U NFC Tag reader which is connected to this user.

I searched for C# code but C# code can't access local resources.
I got two suggestions:

1. java applet
2. ActiveX object.

So anybody can give me the code of java applet which can I use or can suggest another way to do what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NFC Tools for Java](https://github.com/grundid/nfctools) has what you are looking for - a live applet with source code.

Comment: Thanks Thomas but I am not able to integrate this in my Web application